how to fill multiple cell with the same constant formula?
So I want to fill more than 100 column with the same SUM formula (for example SUM(B26:B200) for the entire 100 column). How to do that? Because, if I just drag the corner down, it will change the formula based on the cell. For example, if my formula is on the C26, then if I drag it down, the formula on C27 will be SUM(B27:200). I want the formula to be constant.

Use Absolute references which means absolute column and absolute row:
=SUM($B$26:$B$200)


Here is a documentation on how to use Absolute Cell References in Excel. Those Dollar Signs ($) lock the cell reference to Column B and Rows 26 to 200, therefore when you copy the formula to other cells like fill down or fill right, it wont change and remains as is.



As a reference refer above .gif. Enter = write SUM press TAB key , CTRL + Up Arrow --> CTRL + SHIFT + Down Arrow --> Hit F4 (Function Key) --> Closing Parenthesis --> Hit Enter.

